# Cross origin error on getJson

Tags: json, web-services

i cant get it why i get this CROS error, im trying to get a word in a dictionary doing this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#btnDicionario").click(function () {

    if ($("#procuraPalavra").val() == "") {
        $("#procuraPalavra").val("Escreva uma palavra");
    }
    else {
        var palavra = $(".palavra").val();
        $.getJSON( "http://dicionario-aberto.net/search-json/" + palavra)
        .done(function( json ) {
            console.log(json);
        })
        .fail(function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) {
            var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
            console.log( "Request Failed: " + err );
        });
    }
});
```

})

what i can do so i dont get that error, do i need to pass a callback?:S